# DatagramSocket doesn't receive data

Tags: c#, windows-phone, uwp

I have created a windows socket and send some data. Thats how it looks without any structure.

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
HostName hostname = new HostName("IP");

socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;
await socket.ConnectAsync(hostname, "PORT");

DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
string command = "command";
byte[] packet = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
writer.WriteBytes(packet);
writer.StoreAsync();
```

My problem is **socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;** application never reaches this part.
Capabilities in manifest are selected. 
And i checked everything with WIRESHARK my data gets send and i receive the data(i never stop receiving it, i mean when i send that command server will send answer back all the time without stopping).

Maybe someone can explain what im doing wrong?

Comment: There is no obvious mistake in you posted code. And with your code I can't reproduce your issue. How your server send answer back? Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Forgot about this post I made it to work, had a mistake in command :D but now can't figure out how to read bytes. Have a simple example maybe? Tried many things usually getting cannot convert void to byte[] when trying to read them... Reading string is easy

Comment: There is an official [DatagramSocket sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket) in GitHub, you may have a look.

Comment: Yeah I know this one it explains just about reading string. Can't find anything about reading byte[] Google for two days already. Well maybe eventually i will find something

Comment: I think you can try to use [DataReader.ReadBytes method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readbytes.aspx), this method reads an array of byte values from the input stream.

Comment: Yes that's the one I was trying. I don't know why but when I try to read it to byte[] I was getting error cannot convert void to byte[]

Comment: Could you update your question and share the code you are using now so that I can help you further?